# How to remove a specific string from WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I remove a specific string from WPF RichTextBox (if the string exist)?

To rephrase my question, what is the WPF equivalent of the following WinForm RichTextBox version:

```
richTextBox1.Text = "aaabbbccc";
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("bbb", "");
```

Thanks!

Comment: [MSDN: RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) might enlighten more on RichTextBox in WPF. Look for the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
    richTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
    richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd
);

textRange.Text = textRange.Text.Replace("Text", "Document");
```